# use swift class in Objc project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In one of my projects I want to use a Swift class from an Objective C class. I've created XXX-swift.h file and a bridging header file. Most swift files are working perfectly, but I found a problem of an APiResult class of mine.

```
@objc class ApiResult:NSObject {
var success:Bool?
var message:String?
}
```

and in XXX-swift.h file

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC16RemoteController9ApiResult")
@interface ApiResult : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * _Nullable message;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

there the `success` property is missing. A rebuild & clean build didn't work.

Why is this happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support optionals.  The bridging from Swift to Objective-C allows optionals for class types because those just translate to `nil` on the ObjC side.  However, `Bool` is a primitive type, and there's no such thing as a `nil` boolean value in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, you perfectly deal with my problem.